# How to set a static class to Data Context?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static, datacontext

I have a solution with 4 projects.

In the UI project, I have this XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="QuaverUI.Inicio.Principal"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Behaviours;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuaverUI.Inicio"    
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    BorderThickness="0" 
    GlowBrush="Black"
    Title="Quaver" Height="700" Width="1250" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"Closing="MetroWindow_Closing">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <common:Config/>
    </Window.DataContext>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

As you can see, in the XAML I use the class `common:Config` as `DataContext`, and it is a "normal" class, but I want to use the following one instead:

```
public static class Sesion
{
    public static int idSesion;
    public static string usuarioSesion;
    public static string rolSesion;
    public static string nombres;
    public static string primerApellido;
    public static string segundoApellido;

    public static string GetNombreCompleto()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
            nombres, primerApellido, segundoApellido);
    }
}
```

It's a static class, and it seems that I can't bind it to the UI.

What can I do? What do I have to put in the Binding of the Labels?

Comment: DataContext is a property of type `Object`. You cannot assign a static class to it, since you can't create object instances from static classes. You can assign an object (of whatever type). It's basic C# stuff...  So, either don't make the class static, or, if that's not possible, create another instantiable(!) class with properties which simply access the static properties of your static class Sesion. Then create an object instance of that other class and assign it to DataContext.

Comment: Is it possible to use a static class to dataBinding??

Comment: If you mean binding against static properties then the answer is: Yes, you can. However, if you need to implement property change notifications for static properties, note that these are different from a INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. See here for some details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1) Keep `Sesion` static and implement `StaticPropertyChanged` like @elgonzo suggested;

2) Make `Sesion` a [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). This is a better solution because you have more control on the `Sesion` lifetime. Also, you can use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and other useful patterns that work only with class instances (for example the `DataContext` property), not static classes.

Singleton code snippet:

```
public class Sesion
{
    static Sesion()
    {
        Instance = new Sesion();
    }

    public static Sesion Instance { get; }

    private Sesion() { }

    public int IdSesion { get; set; }
    //other properties...
}
```

And you can then bind the `DataContext` in the `MetroWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MetroWindow : Window
{
    public MetroWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        DataContext = Sesion.Instance;
    }
}
```

Note also that **a `Binding` work only with source PROPERTIES**, not public fields or methods or whatever. And, if you need to listen to the changes in the `Sesion` class, you'll need to make `Sesion` to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695) interface.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot create an instance of a static class, it makes no sense to set the `DataContext` to your `Sesion` class or type.

But you can bind each of the elements to the static properties of this type like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Sesion.rolSesion}" />
```

...where `local` is mapped against the CLR namespace of the Sesion class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm knowing it's two years old stuff, but there is a third solution as follows:

a) create a singleton class, e.g.

```
public class DataManager
{
    private static DataManager __instance = null;
    private static readonly object _padlock = new object();

    public static DataManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (__instance == null)
            {
                lock (_padlock)
                {
                    if (__instance == null)
                    {
                        __instance = new DataManager();
                    }
                }
            }
            return __instance;
        }
    }

    private DataManager()
    { }

    // your stuff as needed ...
}
```

b) in xaml declare the namespace the DataManager is in, e.g.

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyWonderfulApp.Namespace"
```

c) in xaml declare the data context

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{x:Static data:DataManager.Instance"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```